# Why does unity crash when using tooltips?

Tags: unity-game-engine, crash, tooltip

I coded a tooltip by following a tutorial on youtube. At first it worked and now it doesnt. I dont know the reason why it crashed but there was 2 errors saying "NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

"
2 scripts: "ToolTip" and "ToolTipManager"
ToolTip's code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ToolTip : MonoBehaviour
{

    public string message;

    private void OnMouseEnter()
    {
        ToolTipManager._instance.SetAndShowToolTip(message);
    }

    private void OnMouseExit()
    {
        ToolTipManager._instance.HideToolTip();
    }
}
```

ToolTipManager's code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;

public class ToolTipManager : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Camera cam;

    public static ToolTipManager _instance;

    public TextMeshProUGUI textComponent;

    private void Awake()
    {
        if (_instance != null && _instance != this)
        {
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
        }
        else
        {
            _instance = this;
        }
    }

    void Start()
    {
        Cursor.visible = true;
        gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        transform.position = new Vector2(cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition).x, cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition).y);
    }

    public void SetAndShowToolTip(string message)
    {
        gameObject.SetActive(true);
        textComponent.text = message;
    }

    public void HideToolTip()
    {
        gameObject.SetActive(false);
        textComponent.text = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

I don't know what's causing it.

Comment: Look at the inspector of `ToolTipManager` if both fields `cam` and `textComponent` are assigned.

Comment: PS Unity throwing an error is very much not it crashing - when it crashes it either poofs and is gone, or you get an ugly square followed by a bug report form.. your code errored, your code crashed. Unity did not.

Comment: @Bunnly Where did it crash exactly? What does the stacktrace say? As @BugFinder said, there is a difference between an engine crash and your own editor sandbox crash, there is also a difference between an error and an exception. When an issue happens, you need to properly investigate it. The stacktrace is the first tool, the second is debugging (I mean IDE debugging, not spamming `unityEngine.Debug.Log()` everywhere... that is **NOT** debugging). We can't just look at random code and magically guess what the problem is without full details. The stacktrace should be visible in the Console.

Comment: @Bunnly, BTW, that is not the best Singleton implementation. You're missing a null assignment in `OnDestroy()`. I remember the UT guys recommending to specifically call a null assignment after destruction to make sure the native side is "synced" with the managed side, especially on GOs, SOs and MBs. Still, back on topic, I see `cam` variable. Do you have multiple cams? What makes you sure that this is the code that crashes? Did you check if the TMP text has an assigned font that you didn't accidentally remove? Did you check any missing scripts on GOs? Also, post the stacktrace.

Comment: @BugFinder unity poofed. and sometimes it doesnt until i click.

Comment: It crashes in the editor.

Comment: @TheNomad I'm pretty new to unity so I don't know what those are. Please help me and explain things to me.

Comment: Which version of unity are you running. Ive noticed 2023.1.3 i think it is is flakey AF. I added a known good component to my code which was designed to be a singleton cos for the love of all things codey i couldnt find the one i thought was there. It crashes the ide too. Its never done that before. As well. Its not running. So it should have let me add 999999 of them and then delete all but the first.

Comment: Btw. GO GameObject.  SO scriptable object. Right now (as im terrible with acronyms) i can't remember what in that senario MB is

Comment: @BugFinder MB = MonoBehavio(u - depending on US or GB English)r, although, technically speaking, the class name is `MonoBehaviour`.

Comment: @Bunnly I suspected as much and I like your attitude. Unfortunately, there are many new coders that get angry if they are called on it. Let's step-by-step it. First off: technical issues in Unity or in your game, meaning issues in the engine, including internal bugs from alphas or betas or your possibly bad coding/design. The log files are here: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LogFiles.html .  Next: for additional "text" in the Editor (formally knows as *Verbosity*), read https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ScriptingSettingUp.html (and all its sub-pages) .

Comment: Note that production-ready projects MUST NEVER BE COMPILED AS DEBUG. If you want a TLDR, debug builds add additional "info" (markers, file, class internal info, more visibility of code etc.) that give more details when an exception is triggered. That also adds overhead and internal code bloating (not yours, but additional native code is added in debug builds, not just in C#, but in general, say, in C or C++ - so same rule). Production code needs to be clean, optimized and fast. Not to mention too much debug info gives "secrets" away (imagine coding an anticheat or something sensitive) .

Comment: To set the settings about StackTrace verbosity on a project level (not programmatically using `Application.SetStackTraceLogType()` go to the normal Project Settings in the Editor, go to the *Player* tab and scroll down to the *Stack Trace* section. **ScriptOnly** means if it only applies to managed code (meaning C#), while **Full** will also include C++ code. When to use each? Generally, use **ScriptOnly**. **Full* is useful mostly to bughunt alphas or betas or if you make your own internal C++ plugin that is bound in C# (not recommended if you're new at coding).

Comment: Also note the Console Window settings here https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StackTrace.html if you want to also display or **NOT** display something. How do I set my project? I set Exceptions to **Full** (since those might be triggered by the engine and if it's a bug, this will help UT fix it faster, everything else to **ScriptOnly**. If you want to be a boyscout, you can set assertions and errors to **Full** too, but only if you're testing Unity versions, not when making your own projects.

Comment: Best way to separate them: *Log* is the usual text that only has information (you can also supply your own explicitly by calling `UnityEngine.Debug.Log()`), *Warning* is something that is not quite right, but not critical or fatal, but should **NOT** exist in a final production build of a game as best practice, *Error* is usually something you did wrong, but can be fixed, *Assert* means assertions, they are conditions that cause exceptions if they are not fulfilled (for example the existance of an instance - see https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Assertions.Assert.html . Only for Debug.

Comment: So assertions are not compiled in non-debug builds (not to be confused with development builds). Last one is *Exception*. These are usually what you can interpret as "C# crashes". Technically speaking they are not "crashes", but you can interpret it as such because code execution usually stops. What that means comes from the name: everything you code is the *rule*, it is what **SHOULD** happen in your workflow, anything else is an *exception* and if not treated, then it stops everything because the code doesn't know what to do with it (for example, shooting a gun but the gun has no model).

Comment: For actual debugging, here are some simple tutorial examples: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rjNDXKgbhgY and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wt2YdrUlzgg. It might seem difficult at first, but do it 4-5 times and it will feel natural. That is basically **YOU** controlling the whole workflow down to the lowest way to control code execution. Hovering over variables or using the MSVS windows will also show you values of different variables. Best windows to use (please search info about them and what each does) are: Locals, Autos and the Watch Window.

Comment: For debugging, the Visual Studio (not Visual Studio Code) hotkeys are: F9: set/clear breakpoint, F10: step over, F11: Step In, Shift-F11: Step out. For example, try this:in `ToolTipManager.Start()` replace this line: `gameObject.SetActive(false);` with this: `HideToolTip()` which, in my opinion should have been the way it should have been presented in the tutorial in the first place, but that is another story. After you add the function call there, go to the above line and press F9 on `Cursor.visible = true;` so that the breakpoint is on the first line inside `Start()`.

Comment: Atach a debugger to Unity and press **PLAY**. Once the engine calls the `Start()` event inside `ToolTipManager`, you should have a frozen Unity game instance and the Debugger inside Visual Studio should be active on the `Cursor.visible = true;` line. Pressing F10 will step over (meaning it will execute it). Next you'd be on `HideToolTip()` inside `Start()`. Pressing F11 will "enter it". That's called Step Into. If you press F10 you will execute the function line by line or press Shift-F11 to go outside and back to `Start()` (meaning stepping out). Congrats, you debugged for the first time :)

Comment: During debugging you can view the `Locals` or Autos` windows in Visual Studio or even use the `Watch` Window. Do some searching on how to use those. You can even dynamically modify memory so if you have a variable with a value of, for example 6 or false, you can change it to 666 or true while debugging just to see how the code behaves. Also note you can drag the arrow with the current line execution so you can basically re-run code or skip code, but that is not recommended unless in *certain* situations.

Comment: @Bunnly If it's easier for you, I can wrap all this up in an answer and include everything that was discussed and if you find it useful you can mark it as **Solved**.  If not, you can read the separate comments. Your choice :) As long as it helps you. If you have issues, feel free to ask.

Comment: @TheNomad Unity wont crash anymore but none of the buttons or tooltips works.

Comment: How do I mark it as solved?

Comment: You can mark it as answered only by having at least one answer, not in comments. To fix why they don't work we'll need pics of the Inspector properties of all assigned instances of GO that you use in the Tooltip code.

Comment: @TheNomad the crash is fixed so ima mark it as solved. But I need a answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't crash anymore so marking as solve.